# grid.draw Cutting Off Facet Grid Title and X&Y Labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a `facet_grid()` in `ggplot()` and am having issues with the margins of my plot. I am using `grid.draw()` for my final plot, and cannot figure out how to adjust the margins for printing. When I save my plot, it appears fine (see below). However, when I actually print my plot out to hard copy, half of the X&Y labels and my plot title are cut off.

I've attempted using `par()` to no avail. Here is a reproducible example, similar to my actual plot. I need to keep the `panel <- off` part because in my actual plot, I have plotted numbers above each bar and they get cut off by the facet sides for days at the beginning/end of each month. I'm thinking this might be the root of the issue, but I'm not really sure to be honest.

```
data(airquality)

library(stats)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

facet <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=airquality,aes(y=Wind,x=Day,fill=Temp),colour="black",stat="identity",position='stack') +
  #theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(~Month) + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold",size=14),axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold",size=14),axis.text.x=element_text(face="bold",size=10),axis.text.y=element_text(face="bold",size=10))+
  ylab("Wind") +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(5, "mm"),panel.border=element_rect(color="black",fill=NA),panel.background = element_rect(fill="grey84"),plot.title = element_text (size=20,face="bold"),legend.position="right",panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),strip.text.x=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),strip.background=element_rect(fill=NA,colour="black"),legend.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
  ggtitle("Test") 

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(facet))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Thanks for any and all help! Please, let me know if you need any clarification or have any questions.

Comment: if you can save the plot to a file without clipping problems, I'm guessing the issue is with printing. Usually when you print from a pdf viewer there are options to resize the output to fit within the safe print area of the printer.

Comment: @baptiste, True, and I have forced scaling % when I print, but for my own personal knowledge, how would I go about adding margins to this kind of plot? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Are you referring to margins in the plot itself? You might try adding to your 2nd theme a line such as: `plot.margin=unit(c(5,5,5,5),"lines")`

Comment: @MikeyMike -______- too easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options:

- set some margins in the ggplot theme
- assign a viewport of specific size to the plot/gtable, smaller than the device window by some margin. Here's an illustration of using both strategies at once

[image]

```
library(grid)

fig_size <- c(6, 4) # inches
margin <- unit(4, "line")

p <- ggplot() + theme(plot.background=element_rect(colour="red", size=2, fill="grey50"),
                      plot.margin = unit(1:4, "line"))
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$vp <- viewport(width = unit(fig_size[1], "in") - margin, height=unit(fig_size[2],"in")- margin)

ggsave("plot.pdf", g, width=fig_size[1], height=fig_size[2])
```